# Convert a Pandas Column to Hours and Minutes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have one field in a Pandas DataFrame that is in integer format. How do I convert to a DateTime format and append the column to my DataFrame?.  Specifically, I need hours and minutes.
Example:

- **DataFrame Name:** df
- **The column as a list:** df.index
- **dtype**='int64'
- **Sample data in df.index** -- [0, 15, 30, 45, 100, 115, 130, 145, 200...2300, 2315, 2330, 2345]

I tried `pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='')` but it is returning the wrong format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an index that has time values as HHMM represented by an integer. In order to convert this to a datetime dtype, you have to first make strings that can be correctly converted by the `to_datetime()` method.

```py
time_strs = df.index.astype(str).str.zfill(4)
```

This converts all of the integer values to strings that are zero padded to 4 characters, so `15` becomes the string `"0015"` for example.

Now you can use the format `"%H%M"` to convert to a datetime object:

```py
pd.to_datetime(time_strs, format="%H%M")
```

And then use the methods of datetime objects to access the hours and minutes.

Comment: Wow! Awesome!  Thank you very much.

Comment: This is nearly there, but doesn't work for some time formats that include `2400` (i.e. a time offset of an entire day).

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[0, 15, 30, 45, 100, 115, 130, 145, 200, 2300, 2315, 2330, 2345]})

df.set_index('time', inplace=True)

df['datetime_dtype'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%H', exact=False)

df['str_dtype'] = df['datetime_dtype'].astype(str).str[11:16]

print(df)


datetime_dtype  str_dtype
time        
0   1900-01-01 00:00:00 00:00
15  1900-01-01 15:00:00 15:00
30  1900-01-01 03:00:00 03:00
45  1900-01-01 04:00:00 04:00
100 1900-01-01 10:00:00 10:00
115 1900-01-01 11:00:00 11:00
130 1900-01-01 13:00:00 13:00
145 1900-01-01 14:00:00 14:00
200 1900-01-01 20:00:00 20:00
2300    1900-01-01 23:00:00 23:00
2315    1900-01-01 23:00:00 23:00
2330    1900-01-01 23:00:00 23:00
2345    1900-01-01 23:00:00 23:00

print(df.dtypes)

datetime_dtype    datetime64[ns]
str_dtype                 object
dtype: object
```

If you want to get back to this year, you can use a time delta.

```
delta = pd.Timedelta(weeks=6278, hours=0, minutes=0)
df['datetime_dtype_2020'] = df['datetime_dtype'] + delta

print(df)

    datetime_dtype  str_dtype   datetime_dtype_2020
time            
0   1900-01-01 00:00:00 00:00   2020-04-27 00:00:00
15  1900-01-01 15:00:00 15:00   2020-04-27 15:00:00
30  1900-01-01 03:00:00 03:00   2020-04-27 03:00:00
45  1900-01-01 04:00:00 04:00   2020-04-27 04:00:00
100 1900-01-01 10:00:00 10:00   2020-04-27 10:00:00
115 1900-01-01 11:00:00 11:00   2020-04-27 11:00:00
130 1900-01-01 13:00:00 13:00   2020-04-27 13:00:00
145 1900-01-01 14:00:00 14:00   2020-04-27 14:00:00
200 1900-01-01 20:00:00 20:00   2020-04-27 20:00:00
2300    1900-01-01 23:00:00 23:00   2020-04-27 23:00:00
2315    1900-01-01 23:00:00 23:00   2020-04-27 23:00:00
2330    1900-01-01 23:00:00 23:00   2020-04-27 23:00:00
2345    1900-01-01 23:00:00 23:00   2020-04-27 23:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want hours and minutes, then you can use `datetime.time` objects.

```
import datetime

def int_to_time(i):
    if i < 60:
        return datetime.time(0, i)
    elif i < 1000:
        return datetime.time(int(str(i)[0]), int(str(i)[1:]))
    else:
        return datetime.time(int(str(i)[0:2]), int(str(i)[2:]))

df.index.apply(int_to_time)
```

Example

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

ints = [i for i in np.random.randint(0, 2400, 100) if i % 100 < 60][0:5]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ints})

>>>df
0  1559
1  1712
2  1233
3   953
4   938

>>>df['a'].apply(int_to_time)
0    15:59:00
1    17:12:00
2    12:33:00
3    09:53:00
4    09:38:00
```

From there, you can access the `hour` and `minute` properties of the values

```
>>>df['a'].apply(int_to_time).apply(lambda x: (x.hour, x.minute))
0    (15, 59)
1    (17, 12)
2    (12, 33)
3     (9, 53)
4     (9, 38)
```

Comment: This solution is not vectorised.