# In Python convert three lap times (minutes:seconds.milliseconds) to an avg lap

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which amongst other ones has three columns which represent lap times (q1, q2 and q3) I want to get the avg qualifying lap time in a new column. What is the best way to go about it?

```
number  position    q1  q2  q3
22  1   1:26.572    1:25.187    1:26.714
4   2   1:26.103    1:25.315    1:26.869
23  3   1:25.664    1:25.452    1:27.079
```

I tried doing it with pandas but I can't seem to make it work. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: are the types of columns q1, q2, q3? strings or already a time ?

Comment: if it is a string, this should be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61444409/479251

Comment: Welcome. You could improve your post by telling about xhat you have tried, and tell the data type of q1, q2, q3. For example share the output of print(df.to_dict()). If you want to include the possibility of NaN, then please do so already in your input dataframe. Don't wait for answer then ask for extra what-ifs. See good tips in [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always have a `m:s.ms` format.

You can convert directly [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) by adding `0:` to form a `h:m:s.ms` format:

```
df['avg_q'] = (df.filter(regex=r'q\d+')
                 .apply(lambda s: pd.to_timedelta('0:'+s))
                 .mean(axis=1)
              )
```

Output:

```
   number  position        q1        q2        q3                     avg_q
0      22         1  1:26.572  1:25.187  1:26.714 0 days 00:01:26.157666666
1       4         2  1:26.103  1:25.315  1:26.869 0 days 00:01:26.095666666
2      23         3  1:25.664  1:25.452  1:27.079    0 days 00:01:26.065000
```

If you want as [`total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['avg_q'] = (df.filter(regex=r'q\d+')
                 .apply(lambda s: pd.to_timedelta('0:'+s))
                 .mean(axis=1).dt.total_seconds()
              )
```

Output:

```
   number  position        q1        q2        q3      avg_q
0      22         1  1:26.572  1:25.187  1:26.714  86.157667
1       4         2  1:26.103  1:25.315  1:26.869  86.095667
2      23         3  1:25.664  1:25.452  1:27.079  86.065000
```

And for your `m:s.ms` format use a custom function:

```
def custom_format(s):
    m, s = s.dt.total_seconds().divmod(60)
    return (m.astype(int).astype(str)+':'+
            s.round(3).astype(str)
           )


df['avg_q'] = (df.filter(regex=r'q\d+')
                 .apply(lambda s: pd.to_timedelta('0:'+s))
                 .mean(axis=1).pipe(custom_format)
              )
```

Output:

```
   number  position        q1        q2        q3     avg_q
0      22         1  1:26.572  1:25.187  1:26.714  1:26.158
1       4         2  1:26.103  1:25.315  1:26.869  1:26.096
2      23         3  1:25.664  1:25.452  1:27.079  1:26.065
```

Answer (score 0):

If lap times are strings, you can parse them with [pandas.to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html).

We will map a parsing function for each element with an [pandas.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

```py
# Example data:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'q1': ['1:25.187', '1:25.315'],
    'q2': ['1:26.714', '1:26.869'],
    'q3': ['1:26.714', '1:26.869'],
})

df[['q1', 'q2', 'q3']] = (
    df[['q1', 'q2', 'q3']]
    .applymap(lambda x: (
         pd.to_timedelta(int(x.split(':')[0]), unit='minutes') + 
         pd.to_timedelta(float(x.split(':')[1]), unit='seconds'))
    )
)
```

And then, you can compute the average as you prefer:

```py
df[['q1', 'q2', 'q3']].mean()
```

Comment: How can I make this work if some of the values in q2 and q3 are empty they have \N in them but not the actual time? Thank you!

Comment: You can always use a pandas.replace to fill \N with Nones, if you want